# django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "DUPLICATE": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

sql = '''INSERT INTO  EmployeeData_markAttendance(Name,inTime,outtime,InDate)
VALUES(%s, %s, %s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEYS UPDATE VALUES
outtime=%s'''

```
    val=(Name,inTime,outtime,InDate,outtime)
    cursor.execute(sql,val)

    connection.commit()
```

Comment: Can you include the exact error you're seeing?

Comment: You have 5 parameters and 4 values. And you should use ? for the parameter instead of %s

Comment: sql = '''INSERT INTO  EmployeeData_markAttendance(Name,inTime,outtime,InDate)
              VALUES(%s, %s, %s,%s) ON DUPLICATE KEYS UPDATE VALUES outtime=%s'''
    
        val=(Name,inTime,outtime,InDate,outtime)
        cursor.execute(sql,val)
    
        connection.commit()

Comment: Exacr Error return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "DUPLICATE": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not support `ON DUPLICATE KEY...`.
It supports [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) with the `ON CONFLICT` clause which works only if there is a unique constraint in the table, which I assume is defined for `Name`.
Also use `?` placeholders instead of `%s`:

```
sql = """
INSERT INTO EmployeeData_markAttendance(Name, inTime, outtime, InDate) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?) 
ON CONFLICT(Name) DO UPDATE SET outtime = EXCLUDED.outtime
"""
val = (Name, inTime, outtime, InDate)
cursor.execute(sql, val)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "outtime": syntax error

Comment: @TusharNirmal `SET` was missing. I edited.

Comment: return sql % params
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: as getting django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Comment: yes I understant I am getting these error so I try django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting

Comment: @TusharNirmal copy my code as it is and use it.

Comment: raise ProgrammingError(str(m))
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting                                                         Getting above error when I copy and past your code